# Need help understanding an electronic oscillator (Schmitt trigger + capacitor)

Tags: circuit-analysis, oscillator, schmitt-trigger

[image]

When we use this circuit, the LED blinks. I know an inverter transforms high to low voltage and low to high voltage, but here the voltage source is connected to the inverter all the time so the inverter receives high voltage all the time, right? Then why does the inverter ever have a high output?

Also, what's the role of the capacitor in all of this? Here I have the same question as before: it's connected to the voltage source all the time, so when does it ever discharge?

I'm trying to understand this circuit picturing the electron flow as that is currently the only way of understanding it with my limited background knowledge.

Comment: Are you missing a component?

Comment: This circuit will not make the LED blink. You are missing a resistor from the inverter output to the inverter input.

Comment: "I don't understand how it does the latter..." -- do you mean you do not understand how the inverter itself works?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on the false claim that this circuit will oscillate. It won't.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I believe that the OP has an error in his schematic, in which case it's fair to give him an opportunity to correct it.  Yes, this circuit as drawn won't oscillate without parasitics in the inverter.  But if the OP really doesn't understand why a Schmitt trigger oscillator oscillates, then they could have easily left that resistor off.

Comment: @TimWescott Voting to close a question is not a death sentence. They can still correct the question, or re-ask it correctedly; nothing's lost. Still, in it's current form, the question is *ex falsi…*, and hence, should be closed. Hope Surzilla feels encouraged to ask the question with additional background and not omitting crucial details here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I changed the picture and the question. Thanks for your feedback and encouragement.

Comment: @Surzilla revise the question. Note that some of your assertions are not true in view of the schematic. Neither the capacitor nor the “inverter” input are tied to the supply.

Comment: @EdgarBrown I'm not sure how to interpret this schematic then, to be honest...

Comment: Look at it this way: The circuit turns on, the C1 is discharged and low, U1 sees a low input so the inverter output goes high. The high then feeds back thru R1 to start charging C1, when C1 charges enough to be a high on the input the inverter output goes low. The low then discharges C1 until it becomes  a low to the inverter input, so its output goes high ...

Comment: @CrossRoads what I don't really understand is how this can happen if the battery is connected to the inverter input all the time (right?).

Comment: Where do you see that? I only see the battery connected to the inverter's power/Gnd pins, 16 & 8.

Comment: @CrossRoads to be honest I have no experience reading circuit schematics and was previously unfamiliar with the Schmitt trigger, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I'll look into it.

Comment: This has been discussed so many times: [Schmitt Trigger Oscillator - How does it work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169149/schmitt-trigger-oscillator-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 0):

This curcuit might work without the otherwise required feedback resistor - if  and only if the input is not buffered.

In this case the (internal) current for hysteresis could affect the voltage of the capacitor at the input.

Note that relying on parasitics currents is usually a rather bad idea - especially when you can just simply put a feedback resistor between the output and the input.

Comment: … I mean, that'd be true if the leakage current of the cap wouldn't pull it low, while we're starting to consider parasitics. And electrolytics are not especially known for low leakage current.

Comment: I've seen oscillations like these with normal TTL inverters and large capacitors. The characteristics of their input current can be enough to bias them precisely in the middle of their noise band.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that the inverter has a Schmitt trigger input, which has two threshold voltages. When the input voltage rises above the upper threshold voltage the output abruptly changes from high to low. The resistor will then discharge the capacitor until the voltage on it falls below the lower threshold, at which point the output will abruptly change from low to high and the cycle will begin again. So the capacitor and resistor set the timing. There is a curved sawtooth waveform at the input and a square waveform at the output. You might consider building or simulating it to gain some insight. 4000 series CMOS will tolerate 9V.